# Including a Trend Component in a Rolling Regression

Tags: econometrics, model

I am new to rolling regressions, but am currently trying it for my current research. As the post title suggests, I'm trying to assess my specification. What I have now is:

```
ŷ = β0 + β1*x + ε
```

But I'm wondering if I should include a time trend as a right hand side variable. My data structure is time series, 5 years of daily observations. The data exhibit a unit root, I should add. I have looked in the literature, I haven't seen anyone include a time trend. But since my data have a unit root, it almost seems like I should. Perhaps there are many different conventions for denoting time trend and I misunderstood. My statistical package uses the following, which is directly included with the other right hand side variables.

```
@trend
```

I'm unclear because if I **am** adding a time trend, it almost seems to defeat the purpose of a rolling regression (90 day window, 10 period step) of examining the changes in the coefficients over time. Or on the other hand, if I'm **not**, I wonder if the trend will behave the same way in a static OLS regression, and account for trending in the time series, making it clearer how x may affect y, and ameliorate inflated r-squared values due to trending, among other things.

Which specification is the best way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will take a crack at this now that I've had about 1 week or so to grapple with this situation. I think I can now demystify some of the underlying concepts, but if someone can outdo me in this regard then I would invite such answers as well.

The short answer is: Probably a deterministic time trend is **not** needed. If ∆e = 0:

```
∆y = yt1-yt0 = ∝
```

A trend component is justified if there are changes in y as a result of ∝ (trend coef) only.  Unless your window size at each iteration is very large then odds are you won't have a trend for that sub-section. In other words the series at each iteration will likely be a stationary process. A Dicky-Fuller test can come in handy if you don't feel eye-balling the graph is the right way to go.

Seasonal trends are a different story. One tool available is to make sure the sample at each iteration has equal exposure to seasonal trends. The window size will depend on the frequency of your data.